# webView in scrollView can't be scroll?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, wkwebview, ios-autolayout

I had a requirement which was scroll the entire view, it contains the customView and WebView. The struct like below image:

[image]

Therefore, I choose scrollView as the superView to make it scroll. I use the snapkit to layout all views. I added a containView to scrollView which had the customView and the webView. The code like below:

```
func setupScrollView() {
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.edges.equalTo(view)
    }

    scrollView.addSubview(containView)
    containView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.right.equalTo(view)
        make.top.bottom.equalTo(scrollView)
    }
}

func setupHeaderView() {
    containView.addSubview(headerView)
    headerView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.right.equalTo(view)
        make.top.equalTo(containView)
    }
}

func setupWebView() {
    containView.addSubview(webView)

    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.scrollView.bounces = false
    webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false

    loadLocalHtml()
}
```

I had read some documents about how to get the webView's height , it is wait the webView load finished, then set the height of the webView.It can make the scrollView work. So I want to follow this ideas, but I had different situations:

1) I need to load the local html , when webView load finished. I need to make a request to get data form the server.

2) Then I called js method of the webView to fill the data to html. The html contains image and text.

I have think about how to do it. So I get the height of the webView when call js method success. The code below:

```
func updateWebView(_ json: String) {
    let userId = userManager.currentUserId()
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("updateData(\(json),'\(userId)')") { [weak self](response, error) in
        guard let strongself = self else { return }
        if error == nil {
          strongself.settingconstraints()
        }
    }
}

func settingconstraints() {
    webView.snp.updateConstraints { make in
        make.left.right.equalTo(view)
        make.top.equalTo(headerView.snp.bottom)
        make.height.equalTo(webView.scrollView.contentSize.height)
        make.bottom.equalTo(containView)
    }
}
```

But it couldn't scroll, I don't know how to solve it now? Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving the webView a fixed height & width?
If the size of the content in the scrollview is not greater than the size of the scrollview itself, it will not scroll!

It also looks like maybe having a top/bottom pairing AND a height constraint may cause issues?

Comment: Yeah,you are right, at first, I need give it a fix height to webView, when observe the contentSize has changed, it will update the webView's height ,it will scroll.